# create symlink to upload images using paperclip and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, symlink

I am using paperclip in my rails application to upload images. As all know by default paperclip creating public directory in rails path.

But I face a trouble while deploying my application with capistrano. Whenever I deploy my code using capistrano it is replacing my uploads directory. So I am trying to implement `symlink` to create a short since I am not expert in linux I am unable to continue with it can anyone help me how to solve it

```
has_attached_file :upload,styles: 
{ thumb: ["150x100#",:jpg], small: ["75x75#",:png]},
  default_url: '/assets/avatar.jpg', 
  url: "/post_images/post_:post_id/:style/:filename"
```

Here is my url how can i create a symlink for this directory `/var/uploads/post_:post_id...`

Comment: consider storing your files on Amazon S3 instead - that being said I believe that paperclip defaults to storing the files in system, which is under shared in your capistrano deploy and should persist across deployments - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage - instead of a symlink you could also just specify the `path` option to `has_attached_file`

Answer (score 2):

There "right" way to do this is to save files in public/upload/.. directory and ignore upload folder from git. Then create symlink from release current directory to shared directory(MOVE uploads folder first to shared). Add this to `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :create_symlinks, :role => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads" #Create symlink for public files
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/system #{release_path}/system" #Create symlink for private files
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml" #Create symlink for database
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/.rvmrc #{release_path}/.rvmrc"  #Create symlink for rvm
  end
end

before "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:create_symlinks"
```

Comment: whether I have to change url in my model

Comment: Your's images stored in public directory under/post_images. Am I right? If so do following steps: 1) Remove post_images locally and commit to git, then create this directory but ignore from git. 2) Change my deploy example. Replace all my run statement with one run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/post_images #{release_path}/public/post_images". This will create a symlink after next deploy. 3) Log in on server and move 'current/public/post_images' to 'shared/public/post_images' 4) deploy to the server

Answer (score 0):

Using Capistrano 3.

```
  desc 'Persist Paperclip uploads'
  task :create_symlinks do
   on roles(:app) do
    execute "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/system #{release_path}/system" #Create symlink for private files
   end
  end

  after :published, "deploy:create_symlinks"
```